# Lombok documentation and interface in Java

Tags: java, lombok, code-documentation

Normally in Lombok the documentation that shows up in getters and setters are inherited from the field. But I have a class that needs to have an interface. In Java interfaces do not have fields and so I must define the fields in the concrete class. How do I make sure I do not duplicate documentation but still have the documentation associated with the field?

In code

```
@Data
public class MyClass implements MyInterface{
    /**
    *My doc
    */
    final private List<String> myField;
}

public interface MyInterface{
    public List<String> getMyField();
}
```

Comment: No lock when used exactly like you did in the example? Never seen an option for that so you may have to write the getter&setter manually

Comment: If I implement getter and setter myself, then I would still have to duplicate my comments

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to add `{@inheritDoc}` to the javadoc on the field in the `-- GETTER --` section as described in [the documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) and have the javadoc for `getMyField` only in the interface?

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.